# Returning information using who_id

Tags: formula, urlhacking

I'm using the who_id to get the id of a custom object but I would like to populate the name but the code is not working.

Here is sample url:

```
/00T/e?who_id={!Custom_Object__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Custom_Object__c.Contact_Name__c}
```

Here, `Contact_Name__c` is a lookup field to the `Account` object

Comment: Kindly review and answer:
What part of the code is not working? What is expected and what are you getting? Is there any error that your receiving, if yes, have you included that error in your question?

Comment: whoId is for lead/contact Id only.  You need to use whatId

Comment: I'm not able to see the contact name associated to who I'm trying to create the task for, the expected result is for the contact name to be prefilled when creating a new task.  There is not error, the contact name is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The **WhatId** can be used to track the following objects:

1. Account
2. Asset
3. Campaign
4. Case
5. Opportunity
6. Order
7. Product2
8. Solution
9. Custom_Objects__c
10. Contract

The **WhoId** is for these objects:

1. Contact
2. Lead

See [Task and Event Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm) for more detail:

[image: ERD for task and event objects]

Comment: I changed the whoid to the whatid but still didn't work.  Thanks for the diagram!

Comment: Make sure you add attribution when including others' work in your posts, even if it is from Salesforce proper.